# Image saved as base64 shown on the screen

Tags: javascript, image, base64, blob, semantic-ui

I want to show an image that is saved as base64.

it looks like this:

```
const myData.image: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAA...
```

and I'm using Image from [semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/image.html):

```
<Image
      src={myData.image}
/>
```

It doesn't how the image, it shows the string value.

Comment: you can add like `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAA." />

Comment: @aviboy2006 I've tried but still prints the string value

Comment: can you give running snippet if possible to see what is issue.

Answer (score 0):

you must set base64 to img Dom

```
var img = document.getelementbyId('image')
img.src = ( base64 code)
```

or

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
        AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
            9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```